# UIAlertView buttons action code

Tags: iphone, xcode4, action, uialertview

Do anyone know how to make actions for the buttons in `UIAlertview`? if so, please guide me.

Answer (score 8):

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView 
         didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger) buttonIndex 
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"Cancel Tapped.");
    }
    else if (buttonIndex == 1) 
    {    
        NSLog(@"OK Tapped. Hello World!");
    }
}
```

Try This Code It Will Works for you...

Answer (score 4):

When buttons are clicked in UIAlertView, its delegate method

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

gets called. Your delegate must implement this method and check which button was pressed.

```
    - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    switch (buttonIndex) {
        case 0:
            // Do something for button #1
            break;
        case 1:
            // Do something for button #2
            break;
        ...
    }
}
```

If you have multiple alert views, then you can differentiate them by their title as follows:

```
if ([alertView.title isEqualToString: yourAlertView.title]) {
    // proceed...
}
```

Comment: @Malloc use %i buttonIndex is an int not a double.

Answer (score 2):

Read the below article , will help you to understand the `UIAlertViewDelegate`.

[iOS SDK: Working with UIAlertView and UIAlertViewDelegate](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/uialertview/)

Answer (score 2):

Please use this code

First Set delegate for UIAlertView then write its delegate method as follows...

```
 - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex 
 {     
     if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        //Some Implementation
     } else if(buttonIndex == 1) {
        //Some Implementation
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get action for UIAlerView button.

You need to use UIAlertViewDelegate and its method for get action.

For Reference,

- [UIAlertViewDelegate](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/uialertview/)