# Access to Alert Button

Tags: button, alert, alertview

I have implemented an alert like this:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Time Over"
                                                    message:@"Player Two won!"
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
```

Now I want to set `score = 0` when "OK" is pressed. Can somebody help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIAlertView buttons action code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987926/uialertview-buttons-action-code)

Comment: `UIAlertView` is deprecated in iOS 8. You may want to use `UIAlertController` (which has a simpler API) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the [`alertView:willDismissWithButtonIndex:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIAlertViewDelegate/alertView:willDismissWithButtonIndex:) delegate method for button taps.

When a button is tapped, it will be called, and `buttonIndex` will be the index of the button that is tapped (obviously).

If you only have one button, however, you don't really need the index (unless you plan on adding other buttons to the view later).

This should do the trick:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger) buttonIndex {
    score = 0;
}
```

For this to work, you have to change your `delegate` parameter from `nil` to `self`.

---

As [Aaron Brager](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1445366/aaron-brager) [notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29022043/access-to-alert-button/29023538#comment46289809_29022043), if you're targeting only iOS 8, you may want to use [`UIAlertController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/), as `UIAlertView` is deprecated:

```
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController
                                    alertControllerWithTitle:@"Time Over"
                                    message:@"Player Two won!"
                                    preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
```

Then, to add an action, simply do this:

```
UIAlertAction *dismiss = [UIAlertAction
                     actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                     style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                     handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
                         score = 0; 
                     }];
[alert addAction:dismiss];
```

Finally, present the view:

```
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

(If you want to use more than one button on your alert) Reference the UIAlertViewDelegate method here [AlertViewDelegate Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/) and set your UIAlertView instance as the delegate like such `alert.delegate = self;`